# How do I get acces to the parent view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to acces the storyboard from code to be able to use this line:

```
DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
```

I use that in my mapview and listview, but want to use it somewhere else to.
The problem is that this view, is a subview of another view.

It's set up as followed:

thisBigView is a view I added in the storyboard and it's is `ThisBigViewController`
In storyboard I added another view to that view, let's call it thisSmallView. The class is set to `ThisSmallView`.

ThisSmallView is a custom view where I generate buttons dynamically in on the view. These buttons call the following action:

```
-(void) radarEventClick:(UIButton *)sender{
    SingletonManager *sharedManager = [SingletonManager sharedManager];

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"]; // PROBLEM 1

    Event *a;
    for(int i = 0; i < [sharedManager.eventsManager count]; i++){
        if(sender.tag == ((Event*)([sharedManager.eventsManager objectAtIndex:i])).id_nr){
            a = [sharedManager.eventsManager objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

    [detail setEvent:a];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];    // PROBLEM 2

}
```

This is code I'm using in my mapviewcontroller to respond to annotationdisclosure clicks, and want to use it here to, but I have 2 problems!

PROBLEM 1: Because thisSmallView is a subview of anotherview, it doesn't have direct access to the storyboard and don't know how to get that access.

PROBLEM 2: thisBigView is embed in a `navigationcontroller`, but again, I don't know who to access thisBigView, so I can't access the `navigationcontroller`.

(I think if I could solve problem 2, I would automatically be solving problem 1 to?)

-- EDIT: what I tried --

```
DetailViewController *detail = [self.superview.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
```

But then I just get 'property storyboard not found on object of type UIView*'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the subview as a property of the superview in interface builder (control-drag to the header file). Then add a `UIViewController` property to the subview. In the superview's code then do

```
nameOfSubView.superViewPropertyName = self;
```

Comment: I think that might just work! Nice :D! I'll try it now and tell you if it worked, and ofcourse upvote/accept the answer! :)

Comment: Works, except for that I don't need to make a UIView property but rather a UIViewController property. But still, thanks!: )

Comment: Oh you're right I didn't see you were using a view controller. Just so you know Apple recommends against using multiple view controllers to control content in the same view area. You can probably just change your class to `UIView` in the header file and change a few startup methods. Not sure if you'd get rejected for it, but you might want to look into changing.

Comment: I'm not really using multiple viewcontrollers for the same view? The child is a UIView, the parent is a UIViewController. And I just needed to child to ask stuff to it's parent ^^and this fixed it. But I'm not really using multiple viewcontrollers for the same view, am I?

Comment: So you wanted to access the parent view controller gotcha. You're fine.

Answer (score 4):

superview

```
[smallView superview]
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview